# Why is $e^{-i\theta} = \cos \theta -i\sin \theta$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Yeah. I probably just missed it in lecture, but I totally missed why this is like this. Sorry. Thanks.

A part of me wants to understand it as

$$e^{-i\theta} = \cos (-\theta) + i\sin (-\theta)$$

But idk

Comment: Use the taylor series of $e^x$ to see why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the Maclaurin series to prove that $e^{i\theta} = cos(\theta) + isin(\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976017/use-the-maclaurin-series-to-prove-that-ei-theta-cos-theta-isin-theta)

Comment: What you said is actually correct. But since cosine is an even function, $cos(-\theta)$ = $cos(\theta)$.

Comment: and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$

Comment: The proposed duplicate asks about $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, whereas this question asks about $e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$

Comment: The only difference is that you need to substitute $-\theta$ for $\theta$. That is not enough of a difference to not count as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @RaiyanChowdhury . I love simple responses.

Comment: Thank you @J.W.Tanner . You're a boss

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** the $\cos$ function is **even** and $\sin$ function is **odd**:
$$\cos (-\theta)=\cos \theta.$$
$$\sin (-\theta)=-\sin \theta.$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $e^z$ is defined as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ (remember that there are a few ways of defining $e$), we have:

$$e^{i\theta}:=1+i\theta+\frac{\theta^2i^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^3i^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^4i^4}{4!}+\frac{\theta^5i^5}{5!}+\cdots=$$

Knowing $i = \sqrt{-1}, i^2 = -1, i^3=-i, i^4 =1$

We can simplifying our formula $$\boxed{e^{i\theta}\equiv1+i\theta-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}-\frac{i\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+\frac{i\theta^5}{5!}-\cdots}$$

Now, $\color{blue}{\underbrace{\cos(\theta)=1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\frac{\theta^6}{6!}+\cdots}_{\text{Taylor expansion of} \cos(\theta)}}$.

Also, $\underbrace{\sin(\theta)=\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{\theta^7}{7!}+\cdots}_{\text{Taylor expansion of} \sin(\theta)}\iff \color{green}{i\sin(\theta)=i\theta-\frac{i\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{i\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{i\theta^7}{7!}+\cdots}$.

Now, $\color{blue}{\cos(\theta)}\color{\green}{+i\sin(\theta)}=\color{blue}{1}\color{green}{+i\theta}\color{blue}{-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}}\color{green}{-\frac{i\theta^3}{3!}}\color{blue}{+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}}\color{green}{+\frac{i\theta^5}{5!}}\color{blue}{-}\cdots=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: I thought OP was asking why $e^{\color{red}-i\theta}=\cos\theta\color{red}-i\sin\theta$

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your question, before it got edited,

was how we get $e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ from $e^{i(-\theta)}=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)$.

The answer is that $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$

(cosine is an even function, and sine is an odd function).